# How to search for a particular opening on the Internet

Tags: opening

I am very new to forum and formal chess play.  Please bear with me.

I would like to be able to search for an opening that is being used.  How would I search for that on Google or another search engine?  I do not know many opening names, only a few.  Would I use E3 white...etc.?  Any guidance on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a chess program such as [ChessDB](http://www.chessdb.sourceforge.net) you can see something with the phrase "ECO:  B00a [King's Pawn]" and you can go to [Google](http://www.google.com) and search for 'eco B00a' or something along those lines until you come across an answer that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

My advice to you would be to start off by learning 2 openings in chess. Italian Game (white)and French Defense(black), those will help you learn chess in many types of positions, both closed and open games.

http://chesstempo.com/game-database.html

This will provide you with many more openings, and their statistics. Although don't focus too much on the statistics, as those won't win you a game.

Answer (score 1):

You can Google something like "1. e3 e5 2. d4" etc. Or, Chess.com has a pretty good Game explorer: [This link](http://www.chess.com/explorer/). It lets you make the moves, shows how often people reply with other moves, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find out the name of the opening via ECO at a list of ECO codes eg http://www.365chess.com/eco.php you can then search eg '"French Defense" + chess' for 1.e4 e6 on google, youtube etc to find articles, videos on the opening.